# Data fetching approach for secured browsing

Tags: php, ajax, database

My question is related to data fetching. I have ideas of fetching the data from server by using AJAX.But people can see the fetched data in console box. I dnt want other to see it. 
  What I am actually asking is for a good approach to fetch data so that it will be hard for hackers to see it from console. 
      Some months ago I saw a hacking technique in which that hacker get the ID and other information from console, but when I repeated it, I couldn't find that same data, that means facebook changed it.

**So is there any special approach to fetch the data in secure way.**

Comment: this question is solely opinion-based and does not have *the* right answer. Please read how to ask good questions on SO.

Comment: From the server to the client use HTTPS - that is what it was designed for.  If you are worried about what someone who is viewing/interacting with the site can see, well, the are gonna see whatever data is sent to them. You can't encrypt it, it still has to be parseable by the browser.  But you can obfuscate it. What the client can see or the data that they are sent shouldn't give away anything they shouldn't see ...

Comment: ajax is front-end tool used to communicate with the back-end, which means people can see whatever ajax have from console box. so if you dont want the other to see the data, u should use credential/login before someone can fetch the data.

Comment: The problem is not about login, but when I fetch data after login, so I am trying to use encryption on server side decryption on js right now, but I want to make it more secur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is any way that you can hide the content once it is on the client side. 

Now a days there are so many sophisticated tools to see the data passing over the wire.

To secure the data over the wire (transport level security & integrity), so that no man-in-the-middle attack can take place, you can use HTTPS.

That being said, the real question that you need to ask yourself while designing is what kind of sensitive data that you are getting from server that needs to be hidden from the intruders/hackers and more importantly why and whether it needs to be brought into the client side or not?

You also have to understand who the audience for your application and who the threat is from (external or insider).

The topic is very broad.
You can have look at OWASP's sensitive data exposure page: 
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-A6-Sensitive_Data_Exposure